# variadic args of unkown type

Tags: c, calling-convention

Using stdarg.h, I can only pull one type because I have to know the types im retrieving. How then, does printf manage to be a variadic function with any type, in C no less?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`printf()` uses the format string to determine at run time what sort of argument to pull.

I haven't looked at the source to `printf()`, but one possible implementation might contain a switch something like this:

```
switch (type_specifier)
{
case 's':
    str = va_arg(args, char *);
    /* output str as a string */
    break;
case 'd':
    number = va_arg(args, int);
    /* output number as a decimal value */
    break;
etc.
etc.
etc.
}
```

Note that a full implementation will be vastly more complex than this when you factor in all the various types of arguments, all the various sizes the arguments can be, the fact that "%*d" makes an extra va_arg() usage to get the width of the number, and that width specifiers can vary the output as well.

Comment: A real implementation of `printf` is much more complicated than this, but you have the right core idea.  (See for instance http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/vfprintf.c#n108 and http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/vfprintf.c#n509 -- and if you think that's a mess, the one in glibc is even worse.)

Comment: @zwol Indeed.  This is not intended to anything even remotely resembling a fully functional `printf()` implementation.  My intention was simply to show how it is possible at run time to vary the type of arg pulled from a varargs list.

Comment: wow. That mustve been a pain to code, in assembly no less. Regardless, this makes a lot of sense!

Comment: @Riolku Who said anything was in assembly? The code zwol linked is all C.

Comment: isnt printf written in assembvly?

Comment: @Riolku Nope. Modern C implementations will be written in C, because there's no earthly good reason to do it in assembly.  I have actually crafted a minimal (char, 16 bit int, 32 bit IEEE float, string only) `printf()` in Z80 assembler, many many years ago.  It is not something I would suggest doing, it was a major undertaking.  And that was with a functioning IEEE float library, and 16 bit int multiply and divide available to me.  Without those, it would have grown from major to monumental.

Comment: @dgnuff in practice, implementations with no floating point support would invent their own behaviour for trying to `printf` a floating point value.  And the standard requires 16-bit multiply and divide to be available anyway. And 32-bit for that matter, multipllication of `long` must be supported etc.

Comment: @M.M You assume this was for a compliant C compiler. ;)  It was actually for a self crafted "C library" that was only ever called from Z80 assembler.  I'd written the 16 bit multiply and divide earlier, ditto the float library.

Comment: I've used Hitech C targeting Z80 ... it was not pleasant